# Adding webkit-backface-visibility to ion-button in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, web-component

I need to add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` to the `.button-native` inside `ion-button` because it causes flicker some times on iOS devices, I wonder how can this be done, it can't be applied through the opened shadow-dom !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that you cannot mess with this insides, so it's not possible out of the box. This is one of the drawbacks of the Ionic 4 way of doing things.

If it is a bug then you should [open an issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues) on the GitHub repo.

If it is just something specific to you then I guess your options are:

1. Extract the `ion-button` out into your own project, or
2. Do your own custom build of Ionic

Answer (score 0):

I probably will use something like https://github.com/adamlacombe/Shadow-DOM-inject-styles , did not try it yet though ...